# Abstract over lens type to provide better read-write control of properties

Tags: haskell, typeclass, haskell-lens

I'm writing small game-like program using `lens` library and have the following code:

```
class HasHealth a where
  health :: Lens' a Int

class HasPower a where
  power :: Lens' a Int


hitEachOther :: (HasHealth a, HasPower a, HasHealth b, HasPower b) => a -> b -> (a, b)
hitEachOther first second = (firstAfterHit, secondAfterHit)
  where
    secondAfterHit = first `hit` second
    firstAfterHit = second `hit` first
    hit damageDealer unitUnderHit = health `over` subtract (view power damageDealer) $ unitUnderHit

powerUp :: HasPower a => a -> a
powerUp = power `over` (+10)
```

Such code allows me to use functions `hitEachOther` and `powerUp` with any game entity which is instance of `HasHealth` and `HasPower`.

The problem here is the signature of `hitEachOther` function, in current form it allows to write logic which can update `health` and also `power` properties of two entities coming from function arguments, while I want to make sure this function can update `health` only, and have `power` as read-only property.

Means I can write such code (note addition of `` power `over` (+1) ``):

```
hitEachOtherBad :: (HasHealth a, HasPower a, HasHealth b, HasPower b) => a -> b -> (a, b)
hitEachOtherBad first second = (firstAfterHit, power `over` (+1) $ secondAfterHit)
  where
    secondAfterHit = first `hit` second
    firstAfterHit = second `hit` first
    hit damageDealer unitUnderHit = health `over` subtract (view power damageDealer) $ unitUnderHit
```

though I want to prohibit it at compile-time.

One way to fix it is to change `HasPower` typeclass to

```
class HasPower a where
  power :: Getter a Int
```

and it will indeed solve the issue for `hitEachOther` function, but will make it impossible to write `powerUp` function.

I had small experience of using monad transformers and classes like `MonadState s`, so was thinking to try to generalize my code in the same way using multiparam typeclasses:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class HasHealth l a where
  health :: l a Int

class HasPower l a where
  power :: l a Int

hitEachOther :: (HasHealth Lens' a, HasPower Getter a, HasHealth Lens' b, HasPower Getter b) => a -> b -> (a, b)
hitEachOther first second = (firstAfterHit, secondAfterHit)
  where
    secondAfterHit = first `hit` second
    firstAfterHit = second `hit` first
    hit damageDealer unitUnderHit = health `over` subtract (view power damageDealer) $ unitUnderHit

powerUp :: HasPower Lens' a => a -> a
powerUp = power `over` (+1)
```

So it will give required restrictions at compile-time and it also will be very clear from function signature that `hitEachOther` can modify `health`, but can only read from `power`, and same for `powerUp` - signature says it can update `power`.

But such code gives me error:

```
error:     
  * The type synonym Lens' should have 2 arguments, but has been given none
  * In the type signature:         
    hitEachOther :: (HasHealth Lens' a, HasPower Getter a, HasHealth Lens' b, HasPower Getter b) => a -> b -> (a, b)
```

Questions:

1. Why it gives error? I may guess it is because `Len's` and `Getter` are type synonyms, not separate types.
2. How I can update my code to achieve my goal - to have proper control of what my function can read/write at compile-time?

--

Full compilable minimal sample of original code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Main where

import Control.Lens

data Hero = Hero {_heroName :: String, _heroHealthPoints :: Int, _heroMoney :: Int, _heroPower :: Int} deriving Show
data Dragon = Dragon {_dragonHealthPoints :: Int, _dragonPower :: Int} deriving Show
makeLenses ''Hero
makeLenses ''Dragon

myHero :: Hero
myHero = Hero "Bob" 100 0 15

myDragon :: Dragon
myDragon = Dragon 300 40

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let (heroAfterFight, dragonAfterFight) = hitEachOther myHero myDragon
  let heroAfterPowerUp = powerUp heroAfterFight
  print heroAfterPowerUp
  print dragonAfterFight


class HasHealth a where
  health :: Lens' a Int

class HasPower a where
  power :: Lens' a Int

instance HasHealth Hero where
  health = heroHealthPoints

instance HasHealth Dragon where
  health = dragonHealthPoints

instance HasPower Dragon where
  power = dragonPower

instance HasPower Hero where
  power = heroPower


hitEachOther :: (HasHealth a, HasPower a, HasHealth b, HasPower b) => a -> b -> (a, b)
hitEachOther first second = (firstAfterHit, secondAfterHit)
  where
    secondAfterHit = first `hit` second
    firstAfterHit = second `hit` first
    hit damageDealer unitUnderHit = health `over` subtract (view power damageDealer) $ unitUnderHit

powerUp :: HasPower a => a -> a
powerUp = power `over` (+10)
```

Comment: As an alternative to typeclasses, how about passing the optics explicitly? You could add a helper taking “mutable” `Lens'`es & “immutable” `Getter'`s, `hitEachOtherL :: Lens' a Health -> Lens' b Health -> Getter' a Power -> Getter' b Power -> a -> b -> (a, b)` (with `RankNTypes`), as a top-level definition so it doesn’t have access to the full `HasPower` dictionary. Then `hitEachOther` can serve as just a convenience wrapper. Of course, a `Getter x Power` is equivalent to just a function `x -> Power`, so you might as well pass that instead—or just `Power`, though that’s less safe.

Comment: @JonPurdy Also an option, but in this case function will have many arguments comparing with current usage - `hitEachOther myHero myDragon` - I like its declarativeness, it clearly says that `myHero` hits `myDragon` and vice versa without additional details. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Lens'` and `Getter` are type synonyms, so they must always be fully applied, whereas `HasPower Lens' a` requires a partial application.

Rather than parameterizing `HasPower`, note that you can more simply have two classes:

```
-- "Read-only" access to power
class HasPowerR a where
  powerR :: Getter a Int

-- Read-Write access
class HasPower a where
  power :: Lens' a Int
```

If you really want to avoid the duplication, one solution is to wrap the type synonym in a *newtype*, which can be applied (in other words, type synonyms are not as first-class as types defined with `data` and `newtype`). Remember that everytime you use this class you will have to unwrap it, making explicit whether you are using the "read-only" or the "read-write" version:

```
newtype R s a = Getter_ { unR :: Getter s a }  -- read-only
newtype RW s a = Lens_ { unRW :: Lens' s a }   -- read-write

class HasPower l a where
  power :: l a Int

instance HasPower R a where
  power = Getter_ (...)

instance HasPower RW a where
  power = Lens_ (...)
```

Note that some variant of those newtypes exist in [`Control.Lens.Reified`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html), though only the 4-parameter variant for lenses.